# How can I put the results of formatCurrency in a string var?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, format

I see the jquery formatCurrency() function can return the result in a destination, but I don't know how to make that destination a string. In this example I'd like the result to be stored in myDestinationVar.

```
var myDestinationVar;
$( "#totalPrice" ).text( 123 ).formatCurrency( myDestinationVar, { colorize:true, region: 'en-US' });
```

Comment: Yes tymeJV, it's a very popular plugin (which I probably should have mentioned): https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/wiki/Usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not what `destination` means in this case. The [formatCurrency](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/) plugin will only place the result in a DOM element (either its `value` attribute or inner html).

You can pass it a string `destination`, but then it treats that as a jquery selector telling it which DOM element(s) to put the answer in.

If you really want to use that plugin and get the result in a string, you could do something like this:

```
var tmp=$("<div/>");
$( "#totalPrice" ).text( 123 ).formatCurrency( tmp, { colorize:true, region: 'en-US' });
var myDestinationVar=tmp.html();
```

Or if you want the element formatted too, just:

```
var myDestinationVar=$( "#totalPrice" )
    .text( 123 )
    .formatCurrency({ colorize:true, region: 'en-US' })
    .html();
```

Or if you don't want it on the page at all:

```
var myDestinationVar=$("<div/>")
    .text( 123 )
    .formatCurrency({ colorize:true, region: 'en-US' })
    .html();
```